# Joining Four different tables

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem on displaying data from 4 tables, I want to display students names,his/her department,a course in that department, and the marks the student got in that course. My tables are student, department, courses and marks.

**Student**:

```
student_ID
student_Fname
student_Lname
```

**Department**:

```
dep_ID
dep_Name
```

**Courses**:

```
course_ID
course_Name
dep_ID
```

**Marks**:

```
marks_ID
student_ID
dep_ID
course_ID
score
```

I tried to display the data by linking student and department table to get student names and their department,the i joined department and courses to retrieve the courses included in that department but when i tried to join the student and marks table it failed.

This is what the query returned,it returned one student and all the courses in the sports table,which i  didn't even assign marks to. and it didn't display the second student's marks

```
student_Fname | dep_Name  | course_Name    | score
--------------+-----------+----------------+------
Berhan        | sports    | football       |    25
Berhan        | sports    | baseball       |    25
Berhan        | sports    | basketball     |    25
Berhan        | sports    | tennis         |    25
```

This is the data i inserted in marks table.

```
marks_ID | student_ID | dep_ID | course_ID | score
---------+------------+--------+-----------+------    
    1    |     1      |   3    |    7      | 25
    2    |     2      |   3    |    8      | 37
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    s.student_Fname,
    d.dep_Name,
    c.course_ID,
    m.score 
FROM 
    student s 
JOIN 
    department d ON s.dep_ID = d.dep_ID 
JOIN 
    courses c ON c.dep_ID = d.dep_ID 
JOIN 
    marks m ON m.student_ID = s.student_ID
```

As I only have 2 students in marks table, I need a result like this.

```
Berhan       | sports   | football       | 25
Hiro         | sports   | baseball       | 37
```

Please I need some help..

Comment: try `INNER JOIN ON marks marks.student_ID = student.student_ID AND marks.dep_ID = courses.dep_ID AND marks.course_ID = courses.course_ID`

Comment: may you provide the full query please beacuse this one is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print marks in courses in the student's department, you need to add that additional criteria to one of the joins.

```
SELECT s.student_Fname
     , d.dep_Name
     , c.course_ID
     , m.score 
  FROM student s 
  JOIN marks m ON
    ON m.student_ID = s.student_ID
  JOIN courses c
    ON c.course_ID = m.course_ID
  JOIN department d
    ON c.dep_ID = d.dep_ID AND d.dep_ID = s.dep_ID
```

There's also no need to have `dep_ID` in the `marks` table. Since `course` has a foreign key to `department`, putting it in `marks` is redundant: the mark can't be in a different department than the one associated with the course.

Comment: ooh i forgot the dep_ID in student table

Comment: Do you want to print the department associated with the course, or the department the student is registered in?

Comment: Or you only want to print marks from courses in the student's major?

Comment: i want to print the department the student is registered in but it's also the same as that of the course. because a student can't be registered in department A for example and learn courses from the department B. so the department is the same.

Comment: If they can't take courses outside their department, then it doesn't matter which department you join with, since they'll all be the same.

Comment: But that sounds like a strange restriction. Most colleges and universities have general requirements for all students -- math students have to take some English classes.